# ¿Cómo aplicar correctamente la claúsula ORDER BY para dos campos de un tabla en mysql?

Tags: mysql

¡Hola a todos!. Les comento el siguiente problemita que tengo respecto a una consulta sencilla que requiere de ordenar dos campos en una tabla con mysql. La tabla es la siguiente y lleva por nombre *producto*:

```
+--------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
| codigo | nombre                          | precio | codigo_fabricante |
+--------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
|      1 | Disco duro SATA3 1TB            |  86.99 |                 5 |
|      2 | Memoria RAM DDR4 8GB            |    120 |                 6 |
|      3 | Disco SSD 1 TB                  | 150.99 |                 4 |
|      4 | GeForce GTX 1050Ti              |    185 |                 7 |
|      5 | GeForce GTX 1080 Xtreme         |    755 |                 6 |
|      6 | Monitor 24 LED Full HD          |    202 |                 1 |
|      7 | Monitor 27 LED Full HD          | 245.99 |                 1 |
|      8 | Portátil Yoga 520               |    559 |                 2 |
|      9 | Portátil Ideapd 320             |    444 |                 2 |
|     10 | Impresora HP Deskjet 3720       |  59.99 |                 3 |
|     11 | Impresora HP Laserjet Pro M26nw |    180 |                 3 |
+--------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
```

La idea es ordenar esta tabla mediante el campo nombre de forma ascendente (cosa que realiza por default). Entonces, la sentencia quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT * FROM producto ORDER BY nombre;
```

Y como es de esperarse, la tabla sale ordenada alfabéticamente en orden ascendente vía el campo nombre, como se muestra a continuación:

```
+--------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
| codigo | nombre                          | precio | codigo_fabricante |
+--------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
|      1 | Disco duro SATA3 1TB            |  86.99 |                 5 |
|      3 | Disco SSD 1 TB                  | 150.99 |                 4 |
|      4 | GeForce GTX 1050Ti              |    185 |                 7 |
|      5 | GeForce GTX 1080 Xtreme         |    755 |                 6 |
|     10 | Impresora HP Deskjet 3720       |  59.99 |                 3 |
|     11 | Impresora HP Laserjet Pro M26nw |    180 |                 3 |
|      2 | Memoria RAM DDR4 8GB            |    120 |                 6 |
|      6 | Monitor 24 LED Full HD          |    202 |                 1 |
|      7 | Monitor 27 LED Full HD          | 245.99 |                 1 |
|      9 | Portátil Ideapd 320             |    444 |                 2 |
|      8 | Portátil Yoga 520               |    559 |                 2 |
+--------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
```

Ahora, tengo entendido que puedo aplicar un segundo criterio de ordenamiento tomando cada uno de los subgrupos formados por el orden alfabético establecido, es decir, aquellos elementos que comienzan con la letra "D", por ejemplo, los puedo ordenar con base al precio. Entonces, si aplico la siguiente sentencia :

```
SELECT * FROM producto ORDER BY nombre, precio DESC;
```

Yo esperaría que los registros salgan ordenados alfabéticamente como anteriormente se mostró, y en cada subgrupo de palabras que comienzan con alguna letra del abecedario, pues se ordenen con base al precio de forma descendente. Algo así (la siguiente tabla yo la modifiqué para mostrar la salida que espero solo con algunos registros para ejemplificarlo mejor):

```
    +--------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
    | codigo | nombre                          | precio | codigo_fabricante |
    +--------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
    |      3 | Disco SSD 1 TB                  | 150.99 |                 4 |
    |      1 | Disco duro SATA3 1TB            |  86.99 |                 5 |
    |      5 | GeForce GTX 1080 Xtreme         |    755 |                 6 |
    |      4 | GeForce GTX 1050Ti              |    185 |                 7 |      
    +--------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
```

El problema, es que los registros **no** tienen esa salida, sino que simplemente se muestran aplicando el criterio de ordenamiento ascendente por nombre. Es decir, salen de la siguiente forma:

```
+--------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
| codigo | nombre                          | precio | codigo_fabricante |
+--------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
|      1 | Disco duro SATA3 1TB            |  86.99 |                 5 |
|      3 | Disco SSD 1 TB                  | 150.99 |                 4 |
|      4 | GeForce GTX 1050Ti              |    185 |                 7 |
|      5 | GeForce GTX 1080 Xtreme         |    755 |                 6 |
|     10 | Impresora HP Deskjet 3720       |  59.99 |                 3 |
|     11 | Impresora HP Laserjet Pro M26nw |    180 |                 3 |
|      2 | Memoria RAM DDR4 8GB            |    120 |                 6 |
|      6 | Monitor 24 LED Full HD          |    202 |                 1 |
|      7 | Monitor 27 LED Full HD          | 245.99 |                 1 |
|      9 | Portátil Ideapd 320             |    444 |                 2 |
|      8 | Portátil Yoga 520               |    559 |                 2 |
+--------+---------------------------------+--------+-------------------+
```

Cabe aclarar que el tipo de dato que tengo en el campo precio es *DOUBLE*, por lo que el tratamiento es numérico. Lo mas probable es que se me esté pasando algo o quizá no estoy entendiendo como se aplica ese segundo criterio de ordenamiento. Ojalá puedan ayudarme a ver que estoy haciendo mal y como podría efectuarlo correctamente. Saludos.

Comment: Tendrias que especificarlo es decir  SELECT * FROM producto ORDER BY nombre DESC ,precio ASC;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando le pasas a `ORDER BY` criterios secundarios, éstos solamente se toman en cuenta en caso de producirse una igualdad en el criterio precedente. En tu caso de uso, no será necesario discriminar por precio a menos que se presenten dos o más productos con el mismo nombre exacto... y eso no ocurre.

Para lo que quieres hacer, bastaría con pasarle una función del nombre como primer criterio (específicamente, la función "PRIMER CARACTER")

```
SELECT * FROM producto 
ORDER BY LEFT(nombre,1), precio DESC
```

Comment: ¡Tienes toda la razón!. No se como se me pasó, pero te agradezco que me hayas orientado, muchas gracias de veras.